# CSS: How to grow div along with its inner divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsx

I have this `div` with three inner `div`s.

```
ONE - I am div   TWO - I am div   THREE - I am div
```

But in mobile it can only fit two `div`s in a row horizontally, I need `div`s after 2nd to step down.

Like this:

```
ONE - I am div   TWO - I am div
        THREE - I am div
```

How do I do this?

I am using `flex`.

### Edit

I have added HTML code.

I am using React and other UI component and I tried to minimize it in HTML. It's something like this right now.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>ONE</span>
    <p>I am div</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>TWO</p>
    <p>I am div</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>THREE</span>
    <p>I am div</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual HTML, as there only text right now shown in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flex-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp) to continue on the next line. [justify-content](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) will center the div

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Styles below are for demonstration purposes */
.inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner red">A</div>
  <div class="inner green">B</div>
  <div class="inner blue">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for responsive layout, and it also permits them to fit in one line, if the screen size allows it. You can use media query to set it for mobile only.

```
   .outer{
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: wrap;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .inner{
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```